# SSAS MDX Currency conversion based on date of invoice

Tags: scope, ssas, mdx

I need to create a calculated measure in the cube which takes a normal LineAmount and calculates the GBP value per invoice. LineAmount is in local currency.

I tried the following scope.

```
SCOPE([Measures].[LineAmountTest],[Cust Invoices].[INVOICEID].MEMBERS); 
        THIS=[Measures].[LINEAMOUNT]*[Measures].[Exchange rate]/100; 
END SCOPE;
```

It works if I filter by the Exchange rate date for that InvoiceID as well as the InvoiceID in SSAS.

However, when I remove the Exchange rate date from the filter, I want the calculation to know that because I selected that InvoiceID, it should know to apply the exchange rate for the invoice date for that InvoiceID only and not the sum of all exchange rates.

How can I do that?

Comment: It looks like you will have two role playing Date dimensions, an Exchange Rate Date dimension and an Invoice Date dimension. This article, although not directly addressing your issue, might help you get started http://www.purplefrogsystems.com/blog/2013/04/mdx-between-start-date-and-end-date/

Comment: I'm guessing you need to link invoiceId and exchange rate via exchangeRateDate